# Run particular command on particular button's action listener

Tags: java-me, lwuit, codenameone

I have a form which has 4 commands says Action1, Action2, Action3, Action4.  Theses commands runs fine.

Now i have a button says runCommand which have to call Action1 command. how can we do it. that run a command on action of particular button's action listener .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While invoking actionPerformed will work, there is a better and more correct way:

```
Display.getInstance().getCurrent().dispatchCommand(cancel, new ActionEvent(form, BACK_COMMAND_ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

We can use following code to run command in code.

```
    cancle.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(form, BACK_COMMAND_ID));
```